# Rollaxis error from numpy cross product in Python

Tags: python, numpy, cross-product, vectormath

I have been trying to determine the source of my error for this simple script which takes a numpy.array as input and produces a new lattice from the dataset

```
def reciprocalLat(lattice):
    for i,a in enumerate(lattice):
    print a
        b[i]=numpy.cross(a[(i+1)%3],a[(i+2)%3],axis=0)
#/numpy.dot(a[i],numpy.cross(a[(i+1)%3],a[(i+1)%3]),0)
```

When I try vary my lattice or even use stripped down examples and multiple different ways

like

```
print numpy.cross(lat[(1)%3],lat[(2)%3],axis=0)
```

or

```
print numpy.cross(lat[(1)%3],lat[(2)%3])
```

I just get this error

```
ValueError: rollaxis: axis (0) must be >=0 and < 0
```

What is rollaxis doing in this problem and, what is it doing in the capacity of this problem and what exactly am I setting when I assign a value. How do I fix this error (how can something be less than 1 AND great than or equal to 1?)

My test matrix has been:

```
[['4.7480001450' '-2.3740000725' '0.0000000000']
 ['0.0000000000' '4.1118887427' '0.0000000000']
 ['0.0000000000' '0.0000000000' '15.4790000916']]
```

Comment: What numpy version? It seems to be working for me with 1.9.

Comment: i just installed this today, 1.9.2 for Python 2.7

Comment: This should be solved by providing a more explicit error message in 1.10 once [this PR](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/5886) gets merged.

Answer (score 2):

With the newer version of `np.cross` (which uses rollaxis instead of swap), I can produce this error with:

```
In [663]: np_cross.cross(lat[0,0],lat[0,1],axis=0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-663-ee756043fbb9> in <module>()
----> 1 np_cross.cross(lat[0,0],lat[0,1],axis=0)

/home/paul/mypy/np_cross.py in cross(a, b, axisa, axisb, axisc, axis)
     96     b = asarray(b)
     97     # Move working axis to the end of the shape
---> 98     a = rollaxis(a, axisa, a.ndim)
     99     b = rollaxis(b, axisb, b.ndim)
    100     msg = ("incompatible dimensions for cross product\n"

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in rollaxis(a, axis, start)
   1340     msg = 'rollaxis: %s (%d) must be >=0 and < %d'
   1341     if not (0 <= axis < n):
-> 1342         raise ValueError(msg % ('axis', axis, n))
   1343     if not (0 <= start < n+1):
   1344         raise ValueError(msg % ('start', start, n+1))

ValueError: rollaxis: axis (0) must be >=0 and < 0
```

That is, when passing a scalar (or 0d) array to `cross` you get this `rollaxis` error.  So make sure that you are passing vectors to `cross` (i.e. at least 1d arrays).

For example if `latice` is 2d

```
for i,a in enumerate(lattice):
    print a
    b[i]=numpy.cross(a[(i+1)%3],a[(i+2)%3],axis=0)
```

then `a` is 1d, and `a[1]` is a scalar.

---

Is this what your goal?

```
In [675]: lat
Out[675]: 
array([[  4. ,  -2.3,   0. ],
       [  0. ,   4.1,   0. ],
       [  0. ,   0. ,  15. ]])

In [676]: np.vstack([np_cross.cross(lat[(i+1)%3],lat[(i+2)%3]) for i,a in enumerate(lat)])
Out[676]: 
array([[ 61.5,   0. ,   0. ],
       [ 34.5,  60. ,  -0. ],
       [ -0. ,   0. ,  16.4]])
```

I was puzzled about your use of `%3`, but from your comment you are trying to do `b[0,:] = cross(lat[1,:], lat[2,:])` etc.

But `cross` itself is doing that kind of permuted pairing.  From the older `cross`:

```
        x = a[1]*b[2] - a[2]*b[1]
        y = a[2]*b[0] - a[0]*b[2]
        z = a[0]*b[1] - a[1]*b[0]
```

Comment: got any good recommendations on how I could cross (math) vectors a2 and a3 to make b1 (generalized of course), the array is structured such that its comprised of a1,a2,a3 and its dual vector (math) b1 is comprised of the other two vectors divided by the triple scalar product (in comments)